# Write to outState when Onsavedinstancestate isn't called

Tags: java, android

I have an Activity(0) that starts another Activity(1) from a fragment it is hosting.I have set the Up button in the toolbar to return to Activity(0) from Activity(1) and a few more Activities(2,3,4) that might be initialized by Activity(1).

I want to save a variable for Activity(0) so that when it is recreated after the user presses the Up button from Activities(1,2,3,4...) it will return to it's prior state.

I know it is possible to do this with Intents but I don't want all my future Activities to have to know about the workings of Activty(0).

Is it possible to write to the outState in order to do this with a call to Onsavedinstancestate? Or is there a better solution that I do not know?

Comment: I have two question :1)you want to initialize a variable in Activity(0) and when you back to it (Activity 0) , Activity 0  kept it ? 2)Do you `finish()` activty0  after going to activity 2 or others ?

Comment: Yeah I want to use the Up button in Activities(1,2,3..) to go back to Activity(0) and not lose the variable I set before starting the later activities. I do not call finish on Activity(0) in any of the later activities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Activity(0), track a private field with the information you want to keep, and then use `onSaveInstanceState()` to save this field if the activity is destroyed:

```
private String myInfo;

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString("KEY_MY_INFO", myInfo);
}
```

You don't say what kind of information you're trying to save or where you're trying to save it from, but this general template should work. You may need to expose a setter method:

```
public void setMyInfo(String myInfo) {
    this.myInfo = myInfo;
}
```

And you may need to cast your activity if you're trying to work from a fragment:

```
MyActivity activity = (MyActivity) getActivity();
activity.setMyInfo("hello world");
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't `finish` Activity 0 . You can define your variable as global variable.

for example :

```
Class A extends AppCompatActivity{

 public String myvariable;

 ...

}
```